# Why doesn't WinMerge filter .git folders although the FileFilter is in effect?

Tags: git, exclude, winmerge

When comparing git repo clones, I am annoyed by the appearance of the .git folder and its contents in the directory compare tab.

In the Tools -> Filters... dialog, I have the `Exclude Source Control` filter in the `FileFilters` list. Examining this file, there is a line for the `.git` folder:

```
def: include
d: \\\.git$ ## Git directory
```

Why do I still get the `.git` folder diffs in my compares?

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a filter file I defined for my workspace. It seems to work for filtering Git, among other things:

```
## This is a directory/file filter template for WinMerge
name: Exclude binaries
desc: Exclude all project binaries and source control

## Select if filter is inclusive or exclusive
## Inclusive (loose) filter lets through all items not matching rules
## Exclusive filter lets through only items that match to rule
## include or exclude
def: include

## Filters for filenames begin with f:
## Filters for directories begin with d:
## (Inline comments begin with " ##" and extend to the end of the line)

f: \.ext$

d: \\subdir$

d: \.git
d: ZZZ_.*
f: libucos3.*\.a

f: *.swp
f: *.pyc
```

Comment: The files (last 2 lines) should be : 
`f: \.swp$` (not `f: *.swp`) and `f: \.pyc$` (not `f: *.pyc`)

Comment: Am I going crazy or should this be "def:exclude", NOT "def:include" (as in the example now)????

Comment: @tbone I think the intention is to display all the files that are not filtered-out by these rules.